# Unable to call to main Method

Tags: java

I'm attempting to call a method from my 'Clicker' class to my 'Main' class however I keep getting errors, which vary depending on the method I call.
This is the main class. The current error is "Syntax error on token (XYZ) identifier expected after this token."

```
package me.removed.clicker;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

This is the clicker class.

```
package me.removed.clicker;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl.Type;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import me.dewgs.clicker.handler.KeyboardHandler;
import me.dewgs.clicker.handler.MouseHandler;
import me.dewgs.clicker.util.Time;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;

public class Clicker
{
  public static Clicker instance;
  private boolean LEFT_held;
  private boolean LEFT_skip;
  private Time LEFT_pressTime;
  private boolean toggled;
  private Random random;
  private ClickerFrame clickerFrame;
  private MouseHandler clickerHandler;
  private KeyboardHandler keyHandler;
  private Robot robot;
  private Thread thread;

  public boolean isToggled()
  {
    return this.toggled;
  }

  public void setToggled(boolean toggled)
  {
    this.toggled = toggled;
  }

  public Clicker()
  {
    this.LEFT_held = false;
    this.LEFT_skip = false;
    this.toggled = false;
    this.random = new Random();
    try
    {
      GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
      this.clickerHandler = new MouseHandler();
      this.keyHandler = new KeyboardHandler();
      GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(this.clickerHandler);
      GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this.keyHandler);
      this.robot = new Robot();
      LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
      logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          for (;;)
          {
            Thread.sleep(1L);
            if ((Clicker.this.isToggled()) && 


              (Clicker.this.isLeftHeld()))
            {
              long CPSDelay = Clicker.this.generateCPSDelay();
              if (Clicker.this.getLeftPressTime() != null)
              {
                if (Clicker.this.getLeftPressTime().hasPassed())
                {
                  Clicker.this.setLeftPressTime(new Time(CPSDelay));
                  Clicker.this.setLeftSkip(true);
                  Clicker.this.robot.mousePress(16);
                  Clicker.this.robot.mouseRelease(16);

                  Thread runThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                  {
                    public void run()
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
                          AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Clicker.class.getClassLoader().getResource("left_click.wav"));

                        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                        clip.open(audioInputStream);

                        float volume = -9.0F - Clicker.this.random.nextFloat() * 11.0F;


                        FloatControl gainControl = 
                          (FloatControl)clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                        gainControl.setValue(volume);

                        clip.start();
                      }
                      catch (Exception localException) {}
                    }
                  });
                  runThread.start();
                }
              }
              else
              {
                Clicker.this.setLeftPressTime(new Time(CPSDelay));
                Clicker.this.setLeftSkip(true);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
    this.thread.start();
  }

  public boolean isLeftHeld()
  {
    return this.LEFT_held;
  }

  public void setLeftHeld(boolean LEFT_held)
  {
    this.LEFT_held = LEFT_held;
  }

  public void destroy()
  {
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public void openUI()
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] installedLookAndFeels;
          int length = (installedLookAndFeels = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()).length;
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          {
            UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info = installedLookAndFeels[i];
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName()))
            {
              UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
              break;
            }
          }
          Clicker.this.clickerFrame = new ClickerFrame();
          Clicker.this.clickerFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public boolean getLeftSkip()
  {
    return this.LEFT_skip;
  }

  public void setLeftSkip(boolean LEFT_skip)
  {
    this.LEFT_skip = LEFT_skip;
  }

  public Time getLeftPressTime()
  {
    return this.LEFT_pressTime;
  }

  public void setLeftPressTime(Time LEFT_pressTime)
  {
    this.LEFT_pressTime = LEFT_pressTime;
  }

  public ClickerFrame getClickerFrame()
  {
    return this.clickerFrame;
  }

  public long generateCPSDelay()
  {
    int minCPS = 12;
    int maxCPS = 15;
    double minDiff = 83.0D;
    double maxDiff = 66.0D;
    double randomDiff = this.random.nextDouble() * 17.0D;
    return (long) (66.0D + randomDiff);
  }

  public static void setupClicker()
  {
    (Clicker.instance = new Clicker()).openUI();
  }

  public static Clicker getClicker()
  {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

I attempt to call `setupClicker` and even when I follow steps from other pages nothing works,

```
Clicker click = new Clicker();
click.setupClicker.
```

Is what I tried and using other methods also to no avail.

FYI: I'm trying to open the GUI and start the clicker itself.

Comment: You should post the error you get.

Comment: your `Main` class doesnt do anything...

Comment: why  `click.setupClicker.` the method is static

Comment: `Clicker.setupClicker()` is the way you would call that method, but your question seems to say you're trying to call some method of your `Main` class, and I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: Added the error and such ty

Comment: Try what @DavidConrad mentioned. You should put this code into the `public static void main(String[] args)` method

Answer (score 0):

> I attempt to call `setupClicker` and even when I follow steps from
>   other pages nothing works,
>
> ```
> Clicker click = new Clicker();
> click.setupClicker.
> ```

You miss to add bracket

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

          Clicker click = new Clicker();
          click.setupClicker();   
  }

}
```